# How do I configure IntelliJ IDEA to use clear-text password authentication for a MySQL data source?

Tags: mysql, intellij-idea, datagrip

I've tried a few different ways of defining my MySQL database connection in IntelliJ, but can't seem to connect.

Requirements:

- Uses an SSH proxy server
- Needs the password sent in clear text.

My understanding is that the MySQL driver should have a built in plugin for this, called `mysql_clear_password`, and that I should be able to enable it on the Advanced tab of the database configuration by declaring its classname (`com.mysql.jdbc.authentication.MysqlClearPasswordPlugin`) and/or setting the `LIBMYSQL_ENABLE_CLEARTEXT_PLUGIN` variable to `1`, `Y` or `y`.

I can't seem to get it to work. Can someone provide guidance on the correct way to do this in the IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One needs to specify additional JDBC parameter `authenticationPlugins` with value `mysql_clear_password`.
Also, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

Comment: According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cleartext-pluggable-authentication.html one needs to set env variable `LIBMYSQL_ENABLE_CLEARTEXT_PLUGIN=1` and on data source advanced tab you need add `authenticationPlugins ``com.mysql.jdbc.authentication.MysqlClearPasswordPlugin`